# A user is able to see Sharing setting in setup without having "managed Sharing "permission

Tags: configuration, field-level-security

A user is able to see Sharing setting in setup without having "managed Sharing permission" either through profile or Permission set,how can he have access ,Am i missing some configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If they have View Setup and Configuration, they can see almost everything in Setup. However, they cannot modify the sharing settings without the Manage Sharing permission.